# Why is gold sol used for intra-muscular injection?

Tags: surface-chemistry, colloids

In my textbook it is written that gold sol is used for intramuscular injection. But, actually what is its use? Why would people use such a precious element for injection. Can other colloids be used like silver sol?

Note:I posted this question to get a deeper understanding of what is given in my text about the use of gold sol in intramuscular injection. Googling it didn't help.

Answer (score 7):

Will this help?

[Toxicity and cellular uptake of gold nanoparticles: what we have learned so far?](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2988217/)

Gold has a long tradition as a disease-modifying antirheumatic drug in the treatment of rheumatoid arthritis and it seems to relieve pain and decreases swelling of the joints.

Comment: Sir, my question is about gold sol and not nano particles.

Comment: We are not taught anything about intra-molecular injection but,it's given in our chemistry textbook as an application of colloids.

Comment: You might want to read your last comment again. Sometimes our thoughts and our writing take different directions ;)

Comment: Gold nanoparticles are sometimes referred to as "colloidal gold" in mining industry, which I think matches the definition of a gold sol closely enough.